# my flutter app wont start and stuck on loading screen on the phones

Tags: flutter

I have made a weather app (trained by Angela Yu)
I start it on emulator or while my phone is plugged to pc without problem
but when I make APK file and install it to my phone it wont pass loading screen and stuck in that situation.
please help me.

this is my source code

https://github.com/arvan903/weather_app_flutter

I have added Permission request at the starting
tried reinstall the app several time
using VPN or other networks
clear app data

Comment: you haven't added the internet permission in the AndroidManifest !!

Comment: @OMiShah i have added this code but not working yet

<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>